# How to ensure uniqueness for an integer and a string in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, indexing

I have an entity called **Foobar** and I want to add a constraint that ensures there can be no 2 duplicate tuples for ColA (int) and ColB (string), so if the data were added as follows, I would get a DB error on adding line 3.

```
ID   A  B
1    1 Happy
2    1 Sad
3    1 Happy
```

To accomplish this I tried adding Index **IX_ColAColB**.  However I'm getting an error message

> Message=Column 'ColB' in table 'dbo.Foobar' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

If I remove both index lines, the error goes away, but then I can't enforce uniquness on those two rows.  I have experimented by changing **ColB** to integer, and then it works.  Isn't there a way to ensure a string is unique in combination with a number?

```
public class Foobar
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FoobarID { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_ColAColB", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int ColA { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_ColAColB", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string ColB { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
```

It turns out that **ColB** was nullable, but I still ge the same error if I add the [Required] annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max length for an index column is 900 bytes (check this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx)). To fix this try changing the max length to 20.

```
 [MaxLength(20),Index("IX_ColAColB", 2, IsUnique = true)]
 public string ColB { get; set; }
```

Comment: I was just about to post that if I add [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")] that would fix it, but your way is more preferable as it I can also set the length at the same time.